# Magento 1: $productCollection->getData() vs foreach ($productCollection as $product)

Tags: magento-1.9, collection

I have Magento product collection with some filters.
when i call `$productCollection->getData()` I have right result, but `foreach($productCollection as $product)` gives wrong products. 
**why its happening?**

Comment: please provide more data like your code.

Comment: try this:

`$productCollection->load();
foreach($productCollection as $product){
{{Your code }}
}`

Comment: Is tat worked fo you?

Comment: i try add price filter in 'catalog_block_product_list_collection' observer. after $collection->getSelect()->where([my condition]); i try collection->getData() and get array with right results, but if i use foreach($collection as $product) - i have wrong products, not same as array

Comment: what is right and wrong result, can you please help us with the output?