# Magento 2.3 product collection->getData get correct answer but foreach or load() not

Tags: magento2.3, product-collection

[image]Same with here : [Magento 1: $productCollection->getData() vs foreach ($productCollection as $product)](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/227650/magento-1-productcollection-getdata-vs-foreach-productcollection-as-prod), want add more information.
Create new product then

```
$productCollection = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory')->create()->setStoreId('0')
->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', '1638763');
```

Now

```
var_dump($productCollection->getData());  // return the item
foreach ($productCollection as $key => $item) {
    var_dump($key);
}. // nothing in here
```

And try

```
productCollection->load();
```

Both method return null,  Why I can't get the item after load() or using foreach function?

Answer (score 2):

Try to use below in foreach loop.

> First get the data in some variable and loop through that variable

```
$proData = $productCollection->getData();
foreach ($proData as $key => $item) {
    var_dump($key);
    var_dump($item);
    var_dump($item['entity_id']);
} // data will be display
```

Comment: Yes, that works, but question is why I can't foreach productCollection?  When using foreach directly why it is empty.

Comment: you have to use `$productCollection->getData()` and print out some `var_dump($item)` instead of just `$key`

Comment: Why have to use getData() ? What's the difference for using foreach directly and getData then foreach() ?  I see magento using foreach without getData() lots of place. Example : vender/magento/module-visual-merchandiser/Model/Rules          $positions = $this->getProductsPositions($collection, $ids);